# Rails assets:precompile failing during deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I had my little rails-app (based on refinerycms) well up and running when I suddenly realized it had a small bug. Fixed it, tested ok, commit, push, deploy, the regular routine. However this time my deployment (which had worked countless times before) crashed on me during `assets:precompile` with

```
    * 2012-12-21 11:44:59 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
    * executing "cd /home/somename/releases/20121221104442 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
      servers: ["ssh.alwaysdata.com"]
      [ssh.alwaysdata.com] executing command
  *** [err :: ssh.alwaysdata.com] rake aborted!
  *** [err :: ssh.alwaysdata.com] Invalid argument - /nfs/http9/somename/app/ttvz/releases/20121221104442/tmp/cache/assets/D17/790/sprockets%2F159b50b9f479a8cb2519ea6a40f09f92
  *** [err :: ssh.alwaysdata.com] /home/somename/app/ttvz/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:38:in `chown'
  ...
```

and of course a whole bunch of a Stacktrace. I tried to find something on the web but failed miserably. The same thing also happened when I tried to precompile the assets of the `current` version of the app (which worked like a charm in development).

This seems to be different from the other `precompile`-troubles on StackOverflow.

Comment: Check if your deploy user has permissions on your assets or tmp folder.

Comment: I cannot answer my question as I do not know how it fixed it, but I can tell you what I ended up doing. alwaysdata is primarily a Django hosted, but as I could install my own rails that was not too much of a problem. To debug the issue I therefore introduced a `puts file_name` into `atomic.rb` and as miracles will never cease (or it is christmas soon :-) that fixed the issue. However, this left me more puzzled than I used to be (but at least with a fixed app again :-). Any hints for a reason are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried the reverse experiment and removed my `puts ...` and the problem returned. However, even upon reintroducing the line it did not vanish anymore. As I do not have any changes right now that is not a whole bunch of a problem, but it is troublesome that the "solution" seems so temporary or even random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to public belief this turned out *not* to be my error. I started looking up the source of `atomic.rb` and figured that the call to `chown` would actually end up doing exactly *nothing*. So I patched it away not without leaving a message in the alwaysdata user forum. With my (ugly) little patch deployments worked as before again.

A few hours later a friendly staff member told me that this lead him to suspect a recent kernel upgrade gone awry. He fixed it the same evening and everything is working again (without my patch).

Comment: Could you please give me the diffrent steps that you follow to host you refinerycms project in alwaysdata I really need it and it does not work form me :( I use rails 4 and ruby2

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you much here. There are a few forum threads (the latest being [this one](http://forum.alwaysdata.com/viewtopic.php?id=4232)) which deal with running later versions of rails on alwaysdata. Unfortunately you are pretty much left on your own on how to do that. Most solutions involve compiling your own ruby, rails etc. and running on top of `fcgi` which seems a touch dated, but so is ruby 1.9.2 … Maybe we need to find another hosted if the continue with this ancient version of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

It is written in the tutorial of your host (http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Deploying_a_Rails_3_application) that you have to deploy your app in development environment. In this environment, the assets are not precompiled so you don't have the same problem.

I recommend to switch hosts for heroku or amazon, where you can run your app in production env!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I guess I "overlooked" this when I read this tutorial. As I have 3 sites running in "production mode" with precompiled assets this just seems to be a "safe" tutorial. I remember having had an issue upon `precompile` when I deployed the first one, but as it is not a permanent issue there should be a better solution.